# blocking SVN access to certain users

Tags: svn, repository, subversive

All,
I have an SVN repository hosted/exposed over HTTP through an Apache2 webserver.
I have 30 user base, at some point I want to disable the access to most of them except few users without having to change the access policy and restart the server. The goal is to allow only certain users to have access to SVN for a period of time in which other users can not access the repository.

is it possible in SVN?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What you normally do is to change your svn auth file that defines the users, groups and access rights for your subversion repository. See the documentation about ["path based authentication"](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn-book.html#svn.serverconfig.pathbasedauthz) how to do that.

Your workflow would go like that:

1. Download the svn auth file from your server.
2. Change the rules like you want them to have.
3. Upload the changed file to your server at the location.

The svn auth file is read every time a request is sent to the server, there is no need to restart the server.

A variant could be (more advanced setting):

- Setup a repository that contains the svn auth file.
- Define a post-commit-hook that copies the changed file to the right server location.
- Checkout the directory that contains the svn auth file.
- Change it locally
- Commit it
- The server will copy the  file at the right location.

So you only have to update and commit locally, the rest will be done by the post-commit-hook.